# Show $H$ is normal under some conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Problem**
>   Let $k,m$ be positive integers and $p$ be a prime number such that $k$ and $p^2-p$ are relatively prime. A group $G$ of order $kp^m$ has subgroups $N,H$ satisfying the following conditions.
>   (i)$N$ is a cyclic group of order $p^m$ and normal in $G$.
>   (ii)H is of order $k$.
>   Show that $G=N\times H$.

I tried to show this problem. I found that it suffices to show $H$ is normal in $G$ because $G=NH$, $N$ is normal, and $N\cap H=\{e\}$ ($\because k,p$ are relatively prime).

What shoud I do to prove $H$ is normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $G/C_G(N)$ injects homomorphically in $Aut(N)$. Show that the image of $H$ is trivial, whence $H$ centralizes $N$. Since $G=HN$ it follows that $H$ is normal.

Comment: I wondered where I should use the condition '$k,p-1$ are relatively prime', however, I can solve the problem using the fact $|Aut(N)|=p^{m-1}(p-1)$ because $N$ is cyclic. Thank you.

Comment: Yes that is it! Well done.